# Database error, Security processing failed with reason "24"

Tags: db2

In the application logs, I am getting this below error.
Description = [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
While using the same user name and password, I am able to connect to the database through DB2 tool.
Could you please help me to what is this error is all about and how to fix it ?
Thank in Advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

"how to fix it"  For SQL30082N reason code 24, the answer is usually "use a correct password".

It can be that some other application, or other tool, or some other user, is using a bad password, or something is altering the password before sending the password to the database, because of incorrect configuration or incorrect programming. When passwords contain characters that are special to the shell, careless programming can cause the password to be changed because the shell removes the special characters due to programming mistakes.

When too many passwords attempts are incorrect, the user account might get locked or disabled.   This is  not a programming question for stackoverflow , it is an operational matter.

The DBA can use additional diagnostics to determine where the password-request originates (from which workstation/ip-address) and which user-account is giving an incorrect password. The diagnostics are different on each platform of Db2 (mainframe z/os,  midrange i-series,   or linux/unix/windows/cloud ), but your question gives no facts about your environment.